# Unity 3D c# 2 different loops to be run at the same time

Tags: c#, loops, unity-game-engine, void

So i am creating a very simple game, not going to say what it is about because it is a secret, but i have a variable called "rpm" and every frame, it will rotate an object by "rpm". But every second rpm will increase by 0.1, how would i do that, i have tried using 2 different scripts, and also in the same script using threading,  but because i am fairly new to c# i was wondering how i would achieve this, any help is greatly appreciated

script 1

```
public class Rotate : MonoBehaviour
{
    public float rpm = RPM.rpm;


    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update ()
    {
        transform.Rotate(0, rpm, 0);
    }
}
```

script 2

```
public class RPM : MonoBehaviour
{
    public static float rpm = 0.1f;

    void Update()
    {
        System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(1000);
        rpm = rpm + 0.1f;
    }
}
```

all this does is, not increase the rpm, so it stays the same spin rates, but instead of spinning once every frame it spins every second which i don't want.

Again any help is greatly appreciated, and if you need any extra information just let me know
Thanks

Comment: In your `Rotate` script you are rotating your transform to a point, `(0, 0.1, 0)`.  Then the next second, `(0, 0.2, 0)`

Comment: i tried that then it came up with this error code 'Transform' does not contain a definition for 'y' and no accessible extension method 'y' accepting a first argument of type 'Transform' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Comment: @Dominic That error would suggest you were trying to use `transform.y`, and not `transform.position.y`.

Comment: no it still doesn't work the problem is that, the second i play it, it only moves once and doesn't carry on moving

Comment: @jakec 's answer appears to satisfy the requirements, but if you really want to run 2 loops simultaneously, look at [coroutines](https://unity3d.com/learn/tutorials/topics/scripting/coroutines)

Comment: Do not call `Thread.Sleep` on the main thread. What's on the main thread in Unity? ***Everything.***

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a snippet of code that will accomplish what you're asking for

```
public class RPM : MonoBehaviour
{
    public static float rpm = 0.1f;

    private float elapsed = 0.0f;

    void Update()
    {
        elapsed += Time.deltaTime;
        if (elapsed >= 1.0f) {
            rpm = rpm + 0.1f;
            elapsed = 0.0f;
        }
    }
}
```

**Time.deltaTime** is equal to the amount of time that has passed since the last frame of the game (in seconds). The elapsed variable keeps track of how much time has passed simply by adding Time.deltaTime each frame. When the elapsed time is greater than 1 second, your rpm variable gets increased, and the elapsed variable is reset to 0.

I would recommend reading about the different properties of the [Time](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Time.html) object. You'll probably end up using it a lot.

Comment: Almost, `deltaTime` is the time since the last frame update.  He needs to capture `Time.time` and calculate the difference.

Comment: thanks for the help, you have finally got it working for me thanks @jakec

Comment: @Dominic please accept answers when they are correct and have helped you so that people don't waste their time opening and reading solved problems.